# Xamarin App Shell - closing the flyout menu in code

Tags: xamarin.forms, app-shell

The design of my app requires that I have a button in the Flyout Header, a separate view, which navigates to a page

Unlike the flyout items themselves though, when I click on the button, the page loads under the flyout header which stays open

Is there a way to have a button mimic exactly what happens when navigating within the flyout contents themselves?

The page I'm trying to navigate to is registered as a route in AppShell

The code in the view referenced in FlyoutHeader calls it from the button click like so

```
     await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("thepage");
```

As mentioned above the flyout menu is open at this point in order to access the button but when clicked it loads the desired page but I want it to automatically shut the menu

Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: You can use Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;

Comment: Ricardo nailed it. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-behavior).

Answer (score 5):

As  [Ricardo says above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154350/xamarin-app-shell-closing-the-flyout-menu-in-code/60164715#comment106395569_60154350)

> You can use Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;

Answer (score 2):

```
 //===event click or command===
  
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"your others pages route");
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;   
    }
```

Comment: How can I do it in MVVM?

Comment: @Winteriscoming Do the same in a command on the ViewModel class. And the ViewModel object should be set as the BindingContext for the AppShell.